# build and run only one rostest

Tags: catkin, rostest

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have

```
add_rostest_gtest(TestClassA test/ClassA.test src/test/TestClassA.cpp)
add_rostest_gtest(TestClassB test/ClassB.test src/test/TestClassB.cpp)
```

and I want to build and execute just TestClassB and nothing else. I already know how to limit this to only that package:

```
catkin run_tests --no-deps my_package
```

But this still builds **all** the unit tests in my_package. Also every other time I get:

```
IOError: cannot create test results directory [/home/.../my_package]. Please check permissions.
```

So is there a way to build the tests but not to run them, and is there a way to build just one test?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/220047/build-and-run-only-one-rostest/) by [Dimitri Schachmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/22775/dimitri-schachmann/) on ROS Answers with karma: 789 on 2015-10-28

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The answer to this question tells how to do it using `catkin_make`:

- http://answers.ros.org/question/54051/how-do-i-run-unit-tests-for-a-catkin-package/

In summary, the necessary targets are: `tests`, `run_tests` and `run_tests_PACKAGENAME`.

`catkin_tools` can probably build and run those same targets, but I am not sure of the exact syntax.

**UPDATE**: To get the exact target names for package `foo`:

```
cd build/foo
make run_tests<TAB><TAB>
```

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2015-10-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dimitri Schachmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/22775/dimitri-schachmann/) on 2015-10-28**:
True, so `catkin tests` just builds the tests and `catkin tests PACKAGENAME` builds just that package. Still it builds all the tests in that package and I don't know how to figure out the specific test target names. What I do now: I just commt out the other tests in `CMakeLists.txt`. works for me.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can build all the tests for a specific package using:

`catkin build <package_name> --no-deps --catkin-make-args tests`

Then you can use the rostest cli to choose a specific test to run:

`rostest <package_name> <testname.test>`

---

Originally posted by [wmmc88](https://answers.ros.org/users/37721/wmmc88/) with karma: 21 on 2021-01-18

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1